# How to get datasource information from CrudRepository when debugging Spring Boot's

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-boot

I am debugging the a service in Spring Boot that calls repo (CrudRepository implementation).

How can I get information about datasource / JDBC conneciton repo will be using?

Is there an easy way of finding this out without having to call Environment properties, or referring to DataSource bean itself?

The code uses aspects and reflections what makes it not straightforward to look into. Looking into repo returns JdkDynamicAopProxy.

**EDIT:**

I checked application.properties first ok. But Repo behaved in a strange way and wanted to look deeper into it and see what repo actually gets injected.

Thanks,
vito

Comment: application.properties usually have information on URL to connect to Database.

Comment: As per convention the db properties are written in .yml file or .properties file , and those files are registered in Main Application Class , mean main class. You can check there

Comment: I checked application.properties first ok. But Repo behaved in a strange way and wanted to look deeper into it.

Comment: Try changing the log threshold: `logging.level.org.springframework.data: DEBUG`